# what will be data type to store date time in cassandra

Tags: date, time, cassandra

what will be data type to store date time in cassandra

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (
    dateValue date,
    time timestamp
)
```

n my insert staements would be like this ,

```
insert into caliper.log_per_day ( timeStampValue,dateValue ) values ('2015-12-30 16:10:31','2015-12-30');
```

i wanted to store date & time both in one column like this **'2015-12-30 16:10:31'**.
but if i used timestamp it would be store like this **'2015-12-30 04:10:31+0530'**

**Notes** : primary key n other things are skip here... ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

Cqlsh will display timestamps in the following format by default:

```
      yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ssZ
```

The Z in these formats refers to an RFC-822 4-digit time zone,
If no time zone is supplied, the current time zone for the Cassandra
server node will be used.

so if you don't want to store in this way you can store it as varchar.